# Ethersjs estimateGas bypassing insufficient funds

Tags: gas, javascript, ethers.js, gas-estimate

I am using ethersjs to call my contract methods. The problem stems from trying to making the Metamask popup despite the account has insufficient funds in the first place. I am trying to do the popup so that the user knows how much ETH s/he is short by.

I have looked into [Ethers js estimateGas() without needing ETH in account](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/101505/ethers-js-estimategas-without-needing-eth-in-account?newreg=6aea8a368c764de685d3aa6cae1655ae) and https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/discussions/2149, however, it does not exactly solve the problem.

Here is a short code snippet

```
    const tx = await contract.mint(mintQuantity,{
        from: account,
        value: ethers.utils.parseEther(mintPrice).mul(mintQuantity)
    });
```

From what I understand from the 2 links above is that by setting a `gasLimit` will actually trigger the Metamask popup but that requires a fixed value, which may not be practical in production. And that `gasLimit` overwrites the `estimateGas` within the contract method. However, is it possible to call `estimateGas` successfully even with insufficient funds in the account? I have tried writing a separate function to call `contract.estimateGas.mint()` but it with `gasPrice` as 0 but it still does not trigger the Metamask popup but instead threw a `insufficient funds` error.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I cannot get Metamask to pop up when the user has insufficient funds.